# How to load a script in footer in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, performance

I want to add scripts to the footer of my WordPress page. However, they are still placed in the header section. Here is my code:

```
function prd_load_latest_jquery() {
    $wp_admin = is_admin();
    $wp_customizer = is_customize_preview();

    if ( $wp_admin || $wp_customizer ) {
        return;
    }
    else {

        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-core' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-migrate' );


        wp_register_script( 'jquery-core', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js', '', null, true );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery-migrate', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/3.3.0/jquery-migrate.min.js', '', null, true);

        wp_register_script( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core', 'jquery-migrate' ), null, true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prd_load_latest_jquery' );
```

I thought the last parameter in `wp_register_script` will take care of it and place the jQuery in the footer. However, this does not happen and the script is still in the header. What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this way : https://themesharbor.com/move-jquery-to-footer-in-wordpress/

Comment: @Stender Will these lines be placed at the end of my function in place of `wp_enque_scripts('jquery')`? Thanks.

Comment: this is instead of `wp_deregister_script` `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script`. this is the way that wordpress core does it - You can read a little more about it here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/240612/82677

Comment: @Stender I want to load the jQuery file from a CDN. Will it still be possible by the new method you described?